# Basicity of Acetic acid

Tags: acid-base, solutions

Acetic acid is a monobasic acid as it disassociates into CH3COO$^-$ and H$^+$.
Why don't the hydrogen atoms of CH3COO$^-$ disassociate too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of the acidic hydrogen in $\mathrm{CH_3COOH}$ is 4.76. The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of the remaining hydrogens would be of the order of 50. These atoms are not *labile*.

When discussing strengths of acids, we consider the conjugate base. The more stable it is, the stronger the acid is. $\ce{CH3COOH}$ is an acid because is conjugate base $\ce{CH3COO-}$ is resonance-stabilized. This means that the negative charge is delocalized on the whole $\ce{CO2-}$ group, making the anion more stable than, say, ethanolate $\ce{CH3CH2O-}$. If one of the remaining hydrogen is dissociated, this would give a dianion: $\ce{H2CCO2^2-}$, which would be extremely reactive (unstable). So such a species is simply not observed.

Perhaps you had this question because you were thinking of the acidity of the alpha protons (the one you are thinking of) in esters (like $\ce{CH3COOR}$), that have a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ around 25. Malonic diesters can even be deprotonated in aqueous medium. 
The alpha protons are "acidic" because the ester function has electron-withdrawing properties. So are ketones, aldehydes, nitriles, sulfones, etc. The carboxylate ($\ce{COO-}$) moiety already has excess electrons (negatively charged), so it is not electron-withdrawing.

Comment: 50?! I would have thought lower than that. I've seen sources where LDA has been used to form the acetic acid dianion.

Comment: @SendersReagent [Indeed](http://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/chem547/1-carbonyl%7B06%7D.htm)

Comment: `\ce{}` is a better choice for chemistry formatting than `\mathrm{}`: http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here